# Finding mean of middle number of 3 independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, means

The original problem is:

3 workers work on 3 tasks, each require time distributed exp(1) independently. The next task will begin at time T when two workers finished their task. Calculate E(T).

Answer by book: E(T) = 5:6

I understand that "T" is the middle of the 3 work times, but how to find its PDF? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For $t\geq 0$ let $N\left(t\right)$ denote the number of workers that finished
their job in interval after $t$.

Then $N\left(t\right)$ has binomial distribution with parameters
$n=3$ and $p=e^{-t}$.

Further we have:$$T>t\iff N\left(t\right)\geq2$$ so we conclude that:
$$P\left(T>t\right)=P\left(N\left(t\right)\geq2\right)=3e^{-2t}\left(1-e^{-t}\right)+e^{-3t}=3e^{-2t}-2e^{-3t}$$

I leave the rest to you.